# Xubuntu won't recognize Wifi

Tags: wireless

I had a working wifi connection but now I don't have it on my Xubuntu but wifi works in another Windows 10 computer. How can I set wifi to work? When I clicked indicator plugin on Xfce, I can see that the option Enable Wi-Fi is enabled but Wi-Fi Networks device not managed is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to download a proprietary driver for your wifi.

Go to **Settings** > **Additional Drivers**, and see if there's an option to install driver software for your wifi. You will have to be connected through ethernet to download the driver, though.

Comment: There were no driver software to be downloaded and installed.

Answer (score 1):

Some important notes here to keep in mind for a long time:

> There are workarounds for this, first it could be the driver isn't installed properly and there isn't a wifi driver for your OS. Sometimes you should trust the GUI and activate the network from there, sometimes it requires you to activate from there and then activate or restart from the terminal. Sometimes it needs the right command to activate the wifi and a simple `ifconfig wlan0 up` wouldn't work, if you know Linux well, you can try networking tools. And at least no last, configure/create all necessary network files that your OS will need to start that damn wifi, believe me, some OS will require that.

> Then you should know what terminal networking tool does to control and activate your network and wifi. Please go read the manual of your OS.

Don't take for granted every terminal networking tool operates differently and every tool has a config file that should exist, **only if** your OS requires it, that config file will put your tool to operate.

> But only install/activate that tool *if your OS* needs it.

Some tools to remember: https://gist.github.com/miglen/70765e663c48ae0544da08c07006791f

> Finally, check if you need it to turn on your Wifi/Network manually by pressing a button physically or with Fn + F{1,2,3,4,5...} keyboard key.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with XFCE desktop environment on Ubuntu 16.04, however with the Unity environment never any problem. One thing, which really helps me was the terminal command `sudo service network-manager restart`. After you'll see all wi-fi networks around you, but if you disable -> enable wi-fi on laptop, this problem may appear again.